# How to create multiple pages report with report viewer (c#)

Tags: c#, report, reportviewer

i have one report that i created with report viewer. in my report i want to create letter with different data . now in my report only can show 1 rows data of query. if the rows that returned by query more than 1 my report still show just one rows of data. how to show more than 1 rows of queries in report viewer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use table, in the table have three kinds of row, the header, details and footer. Put your field in details row. It's should show all your data, each in one row.